# JSON array does not Stringify properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, mean-stack

In my Nodejs site, I created a JSON array and sent it to the angularJs client. Then it shows as [object, object]. Because of that reason, I used JSON.stringify now it shows in a weird way in angularJs client.

Array creation in NodeJs side,

```js
getAttachments = function () {
        let attach = [];
        workflowSession.files.forEach(file => {
            if (file) {
                const item = {
                    text: file.name,
                    link: workflowSession.metadata.portalBaseUrl + "api/files/" + workflowSession.workflowRef + "@"+ file.name 
                }

                attach.push(item);
            }
        });

        return attach;
    };
```

When I put the console log in the Nodejs side it displayed as below,

```js
[ { text: 'sdee.png',
    link: 'http://localhost:3000/api/files/kYnDsXjyFT@sdee.png' },
  { text: 'wes.png',
    link: 'http://localhost:3000/api/files/kYnDsXjyFT@wes.png' } 
]
```

But in AngularJs client shows it as [object, object], because of that reason I made the changes to the above array creation method as below,

```js
getAttachments = function () {
        let attach = [];
        workflowSession.files.forEach(file => {
            if (file) {
                const item = {
                    text: file.name,
                    link: workflowSession.metadata.portalBaseUrl + "api/files/" + workflowSession.workflowRef + "@"+ file.name 
                }

                attach.push(item);
            }
        });

        return JSON.stringify(attach);
    };
```

Then NodeJs side shows data for console.log as below,

```js
[
  {"text":"sdee.png","link":"http://localhost:3000/api/files/kYnDsXjyFT@sdee.png"},   {"text":"wes.png","link":"http://localhost:3000/api/files/kYnDsXjyFT@wes.png"}
]
```

But in AngularJs side shows it in the as below,

```js
[
{&#34;text&#34;:&#34;wes.png&#34;,&#34;link&#34;:&#34;http://localhost:3000/api/files/saJiCDZPet@wes.png&#34;},{&#34;text&#34;:&#34;ssdd.png&#34;,&#34;link&#34;:&#34;http://localhost:3000/api/files/saJiCDZPet@ssdd.png&#34;}
]
```

I want to iterate this array as shown in below HTML snippet, but I can't do that because of this format issues. The "action.links" is the array created from the Nodejs side.

```html
<md-menu-content>
  <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in action.links" ng-if="item.link">
    <md-button href="{{item.link}}" target="_blank">
      {{item.text}}
    </md-button>
  </md-menu-item>
</md-menu-content>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you logging this on the Angular side? From the `console`?

Comment: How is the array delivered to the client-side? What are you using to set the HTTP response body?

Comment: also, related to Phil's comment, can you check in your browser developer tools network panel how is the response received exactly ? This would help to pinpoint where the unwanted encoding takes place (from Node or from Angular)

Comment: The first example should be functional;  `[object, object]` is a correct output in the console, depending on how your `console.log` was called.  Does the HTML not parse the `object` correctly?

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen yes. used console.log()

Comment: @Phil its REST service, use json as the body.

Comment: @Claies yes. its not parse correctly.

Comment: @manojb86 how **exactly**? Are you using `res.json(getAttachments())`?

Comment: @Phil yes. res.json(getAttachments())

Comment: @manojb86 can you share API code also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Angular side is getting HTML encoded, what you could do is run it through an HTML decode:

```js
var htmlDecode = function(str) {
    var temp = document.createElement('span');
    temp.innerHTML = str;
    return temp.textContent;
};

var foo = '[{&#34;text&#34;:&#34;wes.png&#34;,&#34;link&#34;:&#34;http://localhost:3000/api/files/saJiCDZPet@wes.png&#34;},{&#34;text&#34;:&#34;ssdd.png&#34;,&#34;link&#34;:&#34;http://localhost:3000/api/files/saJiCDZPet@ssdd.png&#34;}]';

console.log(
    htmlDecode(foo)
);
```

Ideally though you would keep it from getting HTML encoded in the first place. If you're able to share a live version of your code it would be easier to debug why this is happening.

Comment: I think this is one of those times where treating the problem would be preferable to a work-around

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen after decode needs to convert back into json then get the expected array.

Comment: @Phil, I agree, hence my note in the answer. @manoj, `JSON.parse()` should convert it back.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen use JSON.parse() after decode from the given method in this answer. It works. I agree with phill, this is a workaround for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify the JS object on the node.js side. Based on what you've provided, the `[object, object]` syntax you're seeing when logging in the console may be okay. Did iteration over the array not work when it was being returned as an array of objects?

If you want to see the data using `console.log` on the client side, stringify the object there:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(action.links));
```

You will not be able to iterate over a JSON array because it's a string and would need to be parsed back to an array of objects first.